# Can I log on to a Windows user account on a different computer

Tags: windows, user-accounts, login

I have an unfinished project folder in a Windows user account back in my school's computer. Is it possible for me to retrieve that file by logging into that Windows user account in my home computer (that is supported by Windows too)? If so, how?

Comment: Windows 10 does not sync the files on your desktop or your user profile files.  Just your settings. If you want the file in question, go to that pc, and retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes. In reality propably not. If you enabled Remote Desktop on your school computer, set up a password for this account, configured the Windows Firewall to allow RDP and also allowed the connection from your computer trough the Firewall of the school then it is possible to connect.